# Swapping the install.wim in Windows 11 installation media would not let me get past first boot

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation, setup, wim

Whenever I swap the install.wim of any Windows 11 installation media I got with a WIM file I captured of my Windows install, it would not get past the first boot, right after copying the files:

[image]

I don't ever recall having get past this every time I swap the install.wim. Could there perhaps be a checksum that setup does so to make sure install.wim is not tampered with? What's going on??

Comment: Does your image contain the edition you’re attempting to install? It sounds like you haven’t been successful in doing what you’re trying to achieve the way you’re trying to do it. The most cause of the error is a problem with the image file.

Comment: I actually created the Win11 WIM from an ISO that I've lost now at this point (lack of storage space). So it wouldn't be a surprise if it's indeed a different edition. Alright, I'll build another WIM from ground up again. Really wish now that I know Hyper-V or WMware.

Comment: What's there to know?

Comment: I mean, I know how to use them.

Comment: English is not your native tongue. I can tell that now. Don't worry, neither is it mine... Female engineer.

Comment: My only language is English....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140848/discussion-between-tempus-nomen-and-ramhound).